# Stuck on simplification of K-map

Tags: boolean-algebra

I've been stuck with this problem because I don't know where I can go or where to start.
$$F(w,x,y,z) =(x\land z)\lor(w\land\neg x\land\neg z)$$
I'm pretty sure I have to do this
$$F(w,x,y,z) =(x\land z)\lor(w\land(\neg x\lor\neg z))$$
but from here on I'm stuck since I don't know how to legally move the $x$ and $z$ around to negate them.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}F(w,x,y,z)&=(x\land z)\lor(w\land\neg x\land\neg z)\\
&=(x\land z) \lor(w\land\neg(x \lor z))\\
&=\left((x\land z)\lor w\right)\land \left((x \lor z)\lor\neg(x \lor z)\right)\\
&=\left((x\land z)\lor w\right)\land 1\tag{1}\\
&=(x\land z)\lor  w
\end{align}$$

$(1)$ is since $a\lor\neg a=1$.